# Hazelcast: How to refresh the Hazelcast Instance?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am creating a service (ReST) which would be up and running all the time. So in this service I am calling the init method from my spring context which hits the database and loads the required data into the hazelcast instance.

Now I have to ensure that I refresh the hazelcast instance by calling the init method. Let's say that the refresh period is every 6 hours.

Is there a good clean way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved by implementing EntryListener interface provided by Hazelcast.
Implement the below methods and call your init() method.

```
IMap<> map = hzInstance.getMap("mapName");
map.addEntryListener(new MyMapEventListener());

public class MyMapEventListener implements EntryListener{
    @Override
    public void mapCleared(MapEvent mapEvent) {
        //Make your init call inside this
    }

    @Override
    public void mapEvicted(MapEvent mapEvent) {
        //Make your init call inside this
    }
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Seems to have been deprecated and replaced by MapListener instead: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Event_Listener_for_Members/Listening_for_Map_Events.html

Comment: Yes. We can make use of `MapEvictedListener` and `MapClearedListener` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hazelcast  eviction policy](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.0/manual/html/ch02s03.html#MapEviction) for this problem.

`<time-to-live-seconds>3600</time-to-live-seconds>`

which clears map content every 1 hour and when any request comes it reloads that map content from a loader.

Below is one of the Hazelcast map config

```
...
    <!--
        Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay in the map. Entries that are
        older than <time-to-live-seconds> and not updated for <time-to-live-seconds>
        will get automatically evicted from the map.
        Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
    -->
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
...
```

Or You can add the time while adding data to cache map, after specified time, specific cache map can also be clean.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the reply. I did know about this i.e. configuring the hazelcast properties like TTL and eviction policies using the config xml, but what I couldn't understand is if the map contents are being expired then how will it call the init method which would then reload the map.

Comment: That thing needs to be handled in your code. Your Rest Api method will call a service layer method which will get the map from hazelcast and return it. Before returning the map back to caller method, check if its null. If null that means hazelcast cache is empty, call your init method to load the data and put it hazelcast and then return. Next time within 6 hours call, map will not be null so no DB call will be made, after 6 hours cache will be cleaned and your init mehtod will be called based upon null map. Please let  me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. The idea is good. The only catch is the response will be slow for particular request which happens just after the 6th hour as the process will start to hit the database for caching.On another note, I was hoping if hazelcast has any inbuilt mechanism(like any Aware classes) to identify that the map has become empty.

Comment: Not sure on that, may be you can go through by Hazelcast documentation, if such feature is supported or not. But with a scheduled job you can achieve this behavior very easly, where job will run after scheduled time, clear the cache and call the service methods to populate the fresh data again.

Comment: Using Payara 5.192 now and the built in data grid with domain discovery, which is not compatible with hazelcast-config.xml. Therefore seems I now have to use the MapListener. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956155/how-to-configure-data-grid-ttl-in-payara-5-193.